# variable scoping while editing R function in emacs ess

Tags: r, emacs, ubuntu-18.04, ess

I'm somewhat new to using ESS for developing R code. When I'm editing functions in an R package in emacs ESS, I get unexpected (to me) behavior when I highlight a line inside the function, and send it to the terminal by pressing `C-c C-c`. For example, if the line assigns a value to a variable, when I switch to the console and type in whatever variable was assigned, it doesn't always print the same variable that I just sent to the console.

I tried to come up with a reproducible example, but I failed. I also tried looking for a relevant section in the ESS manual but couldn't locate it. My best guess is that the ESS R process puts variables in a different environment when the line being sent is inside a function, but that's just a guess.

Can someone point me to something I can read to learn more? I'm hoping to set up ESS so that it behaves like RStudio: any variable sent from a script to the console is automatically put in the global environment, but I want to learn more about what ESS is doing before I try to change anything. I'm using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Functions in R don't send variables to the global namespace.

Comment: no, ESS doesn't do anything with environments when you use `C-c C-c` (`ess-eval-region-or-function-or-paragraph-and-step` by default), it simply sends the highlighted line

Comment: Thank you Rorschach. It must be something else going on then.

Comment: it should be the same as Rstudio (at least from my interpretation of how you describe Rstudio here).  Could it be you didn't have a region selected?  In that case the function/paragraph would be sent.  Or, do you have multiple R processes running?